# return sum of all non-leaf nodes, binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, pseudocode

A binary tree can be encoded using three functions: `l, r and k` such that for a node `n, l` (n) gives the left child of `n` (or nil if there is none), `r(n)` gives the right child of `n` (or nil if there is none), and `k(n)` gives the key value at `n`.

Let `TreeSum(l, r, x, k)` be simple recursive algorithm that takes a binary tree encoded by the `l, r, and k` functions, with the root x, and returns the sum of the key values at the non-leaf nodes. Give the pseudocode for this algorithm.

**However I think it could be this?**

```
TreeSum(l,r,x,k)
  if(l(n) is a number)
  x = k(l(n)) + x
     return TreeSum(l,r,x,k)
 else if ( node is a leaf or is not a number)
     return nil 

 if(r(n) is a number)
    x = k(r(n)) + x 
       return TreeSum(l,r,x,k)
 else if ( node is a leaf or is not a number)
    return nil
```

Not quite sure how to go about this question. I need to find a way to get to all the non-leaf nodes and add the values of the nodes up.

Comment: when you check for `l` and `r` remember that if one doesn't exist it doesn't mean the other doesn't as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

TreeSum(l,r,x,k)

```
if x == nil
    k[x] = 0
else
    sum = k[x] + TreeSum(l,r,l[x],k) + TreeSum(l,r,r[x],k)
return sum
```